# Html.TextBoxFor ID in two places on the same form

Tags: html, razor

Friends,

I'm working on changes to an existing code base someone else created. They used Razor Html.TextBoxFor in many places. I need to add another textbox using the same model property in a second place on the same form:

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EnrollmentToBatchDataContract.NameKey)

The problem I have is that Razor is rendering the same ID for both instances of this textbox. I need to enable and disable the textbox's independent of each other.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EnrollmentToBatchDataContract.NameKey, new { @id = "new id" })
The second parameter changes the Html object values. Any property from the Html tag could be put between the braces and changed.

This does not work on EditorForModel if you need to do that aswell, last time I tried.